# How to detect right endpoints in Sweep-line algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I am wondering in [Sweep line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) how do we detect a right endpoints of a shapes (Circle or Rectangle) as we use a sweep vertical line scanning from left to right ? so the algorithm is basically that whenever we hit a left endpoints then insert into a interval tree of that shape's y-intervals, and when we hit the right endpoints of any shape then we remove it from the interval tree. For example

```
    ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    BinarySearchTree<Interval> intervalTree = new BinarySearchTree<Interval>();

    //sort by x coordinate
    Collections.sort(circles, new Comparator<Circle>(){
          @Override
          public int compareTo(Circle c1, Circle c2){
                return c1.x - c2.x;
          }
    });        

    //here's where the sweep line begins
    for(int i = 0; i < circle.size(); i++)
    {
          //we hit the ith circle's left endpoint 
          Circle current = circle.get(i);

          //insert into the interval tree
          intervalTree.addInterval(new Interval(current.y, current.y+current.height));

    }
```

but when do we know if we reach the right endpoint of a Circle ? Do we need another hashmap for that ?

Comment: You should have a sorted collection of points that generate events in the algorithms. Crossing a circle center does not generate an event, therefore centers have no place in the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public enum EventType {
    START,
    END;
}

public class EventPoint implements Comparable<EventPoint> {
    public EventType type;
    public double x;
    public Circle circle;
    public Interval interval;

    public EventPoint(EventType type, double x,
            Circle circle, Interval interval) {
        this.type = type;
        this.x = x;
        this.circle = circle;
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    /**
     * Compare this EventPoint with another. This is used by the priority
     * queue to determine the "minimum" event.
     */
    public int compareTo(EventPoint other) {
        return Double.compare(x, other.x);
    }

    /** Creates a start event, with a circle. */
    public static EventPoint start(double x, Circle circle) {
        return new EventPoint(START, x, circle, null);
    }

    /** Creates an end event, with an interval. */
    public static EventPoint end(double x, Interval interval) {
        return new EventPoint(END, x, null, interval);
    }
}
```

```
PriorityQueue<EventPoint> events = new PriorityQueue<EventPoint>();
BinarySearchTree<Interval> intervalTree = new BinarySearchTree<Interval>();

// Initialize all the start events, and include the corresponding circle.    
for (Circle c : circles) {
    events.add(EventPoint.start(c.x, c));
}

while (!events.isEmpty()) {

    // Remove the minimum (leftmost) event from the queue
    EventPoint ep = events.poll();

    switch (ep.type) {

        case START:
            Circle current = ep.circle;
            // (Look for intersections in the interval tree...)

            // Create an interval and add it to the interval tree
            Interval interval = new Interval(current.y, current.y +
                    current.height);
            intervalTree.add(interval);

            // Add an end-event to the queue, and include the interval for
            // later removal.
            events.add(EventPoint.end(current.x + current.width, interval));

            break;

        case END:
            // Remove the interval from the interval tree.
            intervalTree.remove(ep.interval);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does PriorityQueue help in this case ? what happen when you call events.poll ? does that give you the next EventPoint that could be either a Start or a End ? because i see you only add the start point EventPoint to the it.

Comment: `PriorityQueue.add()` adds another event to the queue, and `PriorityQueue.poll()` removes and returns the *minimum* one. I add `START` events at the beginning, and `END` events whenever a `START` event is encountered. The `END` events also includes a reference to the `Interval` that was created.